# Adjective for fixed false / druggy smile? Sounds like a drug maybe

Tags: single-word-requests

Just outside conscious mind Im trying to remember an adjective fitting that description. Might have "ch" in it, might end in "ic". May well be linked to a specific drug.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be the word `Bacchic`? In the sense of "drunken and debauched."

Comment: Thank you Tushar! But this is a word I probably picked up in crime fiction, where people are often using or subdued with drugs; I think it may well contain the name.of drug in the adjective.

Comment: Hmm. Is it a long word or a short one?

Comment: Were you thinking of Antiseptic?

Comment: "antiseptic smile"? - no, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **saccharine** adj.
>
> 3. cloyingly agreeable or ingratiating.
> 4. exaggeratedly sweet or sentimental.

[[RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/saccharine)]

> 2. Having a cloyingly sweet attitude, tone, or character: *a saccharine smile*.

[AHD]

> too sweet or too polite:
>
> *I don't trust her, with her saccharine smiles.*

[[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/saccharine)]

Comment: First time ever Ive used this site; searched for.a forum like this and pow! V pleased and grateful!

Answer (score 0):

How about melancholic or glazed?

Comment: I think the context will help. I was writing to a friend about our local council which makes a big deal twice a year of asking for our feedback and suggestions as if they're really interested. My personal experience, by email and phone chat, has been that this is a very superficial exercise they go through, and I was thinking of a particular town clerk, beaming as she requests people's feedback, while perhaps her real goal underneath is to give a good image of the council and protect her job.

Comment: Btw - can you pls explain to a newbie the customary use of Upgrade / Downgrade / Tick? Thanks

Comment: Sure upvote/downvote is the obvious way to endorse an answer (or otherwise) The tick is what you use to accept an anaswer as being the correct answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks - is the tick used only if it's 'the answer'? ie not if it's valuable and interesting?

Comment: you should select an answer that is the most useful and allocate the tick to that one. The up/down is separate and can be used multiple times.

Comment: id say insincere may be the best word for you in that context

Comment: thanks again. I like saccharine - it's insincere sugar :)